# Copying BLOB from one server to another

Tags: mysql, blob

I have a huge table that contains 20K records with BLOB (picture) coloumn.Its located in Localhost port 3308 in XAMPP Portable.
Now i need to move this table to another database (port 3306) in the same server.

I try to copy-paste all records (copy from 3308, paste to 3306) it directly (using Navicat) but it failed. 
I try to copy-paste the records partially (5K records at a time). It still fails.
the errors are the same : mysql server has gone away. it seems that the data is too large to be copied into.

How can i possibly do this ?

The "server" is : Win 7 64 bit, 6Gb Ram, Core i3. (i know, its far from server spec.). I have 2 mysql server running, one at port 3306 running native Mysql and the other one running with XAMPP at port 3308

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the data from command line with

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [database-name] > file-name.sql
```

That will prompt you for the password.
Then you need to transfer it to the other machine, and import it with

```
mysql -u [username2] -p [database-name2] < file-name.sql
```